# synchronized section inside constructor and syncronized constructor differences

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, synchronized

I noticed interesting behaviour:

I can write

```
class My {
     public My(){
        synchronized(this){
            // code
        }

    }  
}
```

but I cannot write

```
class My {
         public synchronized My(){
                // code
            }

        }  
    }
```

I thought that both constructions works identically terms java API.

Please clarify this misunderstanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't Java constructors be synchronized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880168/why-cant-java-constructors-be-synchronized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, the object is almost created, only the body of the Constructor need to executed.

But, in the second case, there won't any object to synchronize.

Comment: just now I have understood that your answer is incorrect because constructor performed after initialize block. But inside  initialize block I can write syncronized section with monitor this. What do you think ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow, before initialized block called, super class constructor will be executed and the object will almost created.

Comment: please realize my comment.

Comment: @gstackoverflow : You can do that, because, it's already completed it's super class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible situation that two Threads will create same object !

Thus synchronized modificator hasn't sense for constructor.